# Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : cannot coerce class ‘"mids"’ to a data.frame

Tags: r, rstudio, imputar

me encuentro con el siguiente error que no consigo solucionar. Estoy trabajando con métodos de imputación de datos, y en la imputación de media hago gráfico para ver patrón de datos faltantes. Como comprobación, después hago gráfica con los datos ya imputados, para probar que todos los datos no son de tipo faltante. Sin embargo, obtengo el error especificado en el título. ¿Alguien sabe como solventarlo?

```
library(NHANES)
library(VIM)
data(NHANES)
names(NHANES)[names(NHANES) == "PhysActive"] <- "PhysAct"

NHANES %>%
  count(ID, sort = TRUE)

#eliminamos filas repetidas
filtered_nhan <- NHANES %>% distinct()

filtered_nhan %>%
  count(ID, sort = TRUE)


df_nhan <- slice(filtered_nhan, 1:1000) %>%
  select(ID, Age, Gender, Weight, Height, TotChol, Diabetes, Pulse, PhysAct)

small_nhan <- select(df_nhan, -PhysAct, -Diabetes)

NHAN_mean_imput <- mice(small_nhan, method="mean",m=1, maxit=1)
NHAN_mean_imput$meth  # verificación del mod. de imputación empleado en cada var

aggr.plot2 <- aggr(NHAN_mean_imput, col=c('cadetblue1', 'brown3'), numbers=TRUE,
                  sortVars= TRUE, cex.axis=.8, gap=3,ylab = c('Histograma datos faltantes', 'Patrón'))  #esta es la gráfica que da fallo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error nos dice que el objeto que quieres graficar no corresponde a un data frame,
y que corresponde a uno de clase 'mids'

esto lo puedes comprobar con:

```
class(NHAN_mean_imput)
```

ya que efectivamente estas intentado graficar NHAN_mean_imput que corresponde a una lista.

en tu caso en particular, creo que lo quieres es graficar el data que esta contenido en esa lista, esto lo puedes hacer accediendo directamente con el símbolo $ o con los [[]]

```
aggr.plot2 <- aggr(NHAN_mean_imput$data, col=c('cadetblue1', 'brown3'), numbers=TRUE,
              sortVars= TRUE, cex.axis=.8, gap=3,ylab = c('Histograma datos faltantes', 'Patrón'))  #esta es la gráfica que da fallo
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no sabía cómo solucionarlo! Con esto ya queda arreglado :)